# PHP replacing literal \r\n with <br/> (not replacing new lines)

Tags: php, html, regex, string

Basically I have this script that I'm trying to replace the literal text `\r\n` with `<br />` for proper formatting. I've tried `nl2br()` and it didn't replace the `\r\n` with `<br />`. Here's the code.

```
$title = isset($post[0]) ? $post[0] : false;
$body = isset($post[1]) ? preg_replace('#(\r|\r\n|\n)#', '<br/>', $post[1]) : false;
echo $title."<br/>".$body;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it did not work?' Did not replace the newlines? Failed with error message?

Comment: Didn't replace them with new lines.

Comment: Your code is correct. What is the output (`$body`) you get instead and what do you get when you use `nl2br`? Are you sure your input contains `\r`, `\n` etc?

Comment: what is your php version? `nl2br()` in [v5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) has added an optional `is_xhtml` parameter, maybe you should set it to false.

Comment: Input and output come out the same for some reason. The input is "You see, \r\n this is a new section.", the output being the same.

Comment: You want to go backwards from `<br>` to `\r\n`?

Comment: I want to go from \r\n to <br/>

Comment: Your code is replacing newlines with `<br/>` but you say "I've tried `nl2br()` and it didn't replace the `<br/>` with newlines.". Are you trying to replace `<br/>` with newlines or are you trying to replace newlines with `<br/>`?

Comment: How do you see the \r \n ? Are you looking at the HTML output?

Comment: It's displaying the \r\n in my HTML code for some reason.. Maybe because the input is coming from a text file?

Comment: I've just noticed that Ben, typo, changed.

Comment: If you can *see* \r\n literally in the HTML, then they're not really the single character `\n` and the single character `\r`

Comment: Re: *"You see, \r\n this is a new section."* -- is `\r\n` a literal *\r\n* or a windows new line?

Comment: The txt document: `<b>Title 1</b>[ENDSECTION]You see, \r\n this is a new section.[ENDSECTION]` ($post is an array exploded by [ENDSECTION])

Comment: The regex is not fully correct. If the text has \r\n, the first \r will turn to <br /> and the \n will get to <br /> also. So you end up with two <br />

Comment: George, I'm ending up with none.

Comment: `nl2br()` does _not_ transform literals like `'\r'` or `'\n'`, but only real CR `chr(13)` and real LF `chr(10)` bytes.

Comment: It should be a Windows CRLF where CR is the single character `\r` and LF is the single character `\n`

Comment: Surely the Regex should transform literals though?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$body = isset($post[1]) ? preg_replace('#(\\\r|\\\r\\\n|\\\n)#', '<br/>', $post[1]) : false;
```

You'll need three `\\\`. Inside single quotes, `\\` translates to `\` so `\\\r` becomes `\\r` which gets fed to the `preg_replace` funciton.

PREG engine has its own set of escape sequences and `\r` is one of them which means ASCII character #13. To tell PREG engine to search for the literal `\r`, you need to pass the string `\\r` which needs to be escaped once more since you have it inside single quotes.

Comment: It's working now. The code I'm using: `$body = isset($post[1]) ? preg_replace('#(\\\r|\\\r\\\n|\\\n)#', '<br/>', $post[1]) : false;`

Comment: @Josh: I missed out the third slash before the last `n`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @FutureReaders See `Explosion Pills` answer below if getting `\n` in html text

Answer (score 4):

If it's displaying `\r` and `\n` in your html, that means that these are not newlines and line breaks, but escaped backslashes followed by an r or an n (`\\r` for example).  You need to strip these slashes or update your regex to account for them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$body = nl2br(strtr($post[1], array('\r' => chr(13), '\n' => chr(10))));
```

Answer (score 2):

try the [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

```
$title = isset($post[0]) ? $post[0] : false;
$body = isset($post[1]) ? str_replace(array('\r\n', '\r', '\n'), '<br/>', $post[1]) : false;
echo $title."<br/>".$body;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @tandu mentioned if you're seeing `\r` or `\n` in the html then you need to use `stripslashes()` first before applying `nl2br()`. The slashes are automatically added if you're data is coming from a form.

So your code would become:

```
$title = isset($post[0]) ? nl2br(stripslashes($post[0])) : false;
$body = isset($post[1]) ? nl2br(stripslashes($post[1])) : false;
echo $title."<br/>".$body;
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
Um..just another thought. Should you be using $_POST[0] and $_POST[1]?

Answer (score 1):

As I read the comments of the question I would suggest to try following code:

```
$title = isset($post[0]) ? $post[0] : false;
$body = isset($post[1]) ? preg_replace('#(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)#', '<br/>', $post[1]) : false;
echo $title."<br/>".$body;
```

Comment: You should update  your question with a sample of the input, so we can better find where is the problem.